# store cpu temperature in variable

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep, temperature

I am trying to parse out the temperature information from what lm-sensors provides in the Linux shell command: `$sensors`

I suspect I am muddling this more than necessary. First: is there a pre-existing environmental variable or something for CPU temperature?

I tried using the command:

```
$ sensors -A -f | awk '{print $2}'

+136.4°F
```

but I get some undesired white space, and some unwanted other characters. such as +. degree sign, F.

so then I tried my hand at greping the digits out with:
`sensors -A -f | awk '{print $2}' | egrep -o [0-9]\.?[0-9]`
but every time, I get the digits before the decimal, but I cant seem to get the digits after the decimal.

All I want to do is get the system cpu temp into a variable. Is this the best route to go about it? please assist me in getting the cpu temperature.

UPDATE:

`sensors -A -f | awk '{print $2+0}'
0
77
0`

which replaces the white spaces with 0's, and still doesn't give the number after the decimal.

Comment: Could you update the question with the output of `sensors -A -f` and the part you want extracted?

Comment: Copy the command `sensors -A -f`, execute it in your command prompt, copy the output, click on [*Edit*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24847010/edit) under the question, paste the output, select it, press Ctrl + K, and click *Save Edits*.

Comment: @j0h: Re the update, see updated asnwer

Answer (score 4):

In general, there is no need to use `grep` when you are already using awk. Your command could probably be simplified to:

```
sensors -A -f | awk '{print $2+0}'
```

Test:

```
$ awk '{print $2+0}' <<< "abc +136.4°F"
136.4
```

To only print the line for which the second column is a (non-zero) number, you can do:

```
awk '$2+0 {print $2+0}'
```

Comment: +1; takes advantage of `awk` interpreting anything that *starts* with a number representation as that number in a numerical context (forced with `+0`). To also ignore blank lines, use `awk '$0 != "" {print $2+0}`.

Comment: @mklement0 to ignore the blank lines you should do `awk 'NF{print $2+0}'`

Comment: @jaypal: Good point, thanks (`$0 != ""` only ignores truly _empty_ lines, while `NF` (or `NF>0`) ignores blank lines - i.e., empty _or all-whitespace_ lines).

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matched a single digit, an (optional) decimal decimal point, and then another single digit.

Try this regex:

```
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?
```

This matches multiple digits followed optionally by a decimal point and more digits.  Note the `'+'` which means "one or more" and the `(...)` group.

(For completeness, you probably should include a leading `'-'` in the regex ... but somehow, I think you are unlikely to see that in practice.)

Comment: Also single-quote the argument of egrep otherwise it will be subject to filename expansion like `... | egrep -o '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export LC_ALL=C
sensors -A -f | awk 'NF{print $2+0}'
```

I suspect the problem you're having is that your default LOCALE uses commas instead of periods to separate numbers.

If that's not it then, as requested a couple of times already, PLEASE update your question to show the output of `sensors -A -f` on your system to give us a chance at being able to help you.

Answer (score -1):

If python works for you...

```
import subprocess
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["sensors"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p1.communicate()
A = output[0]
temp = float(A[56:60])
```

Output:

```
In [10]: temp
Out[10]: 57.0
```